# a change with visudo doesn't work

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I issue visudo command, add this rule to the very end of the file, save the file and quit.

```
newuser    ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd
```

However newuser is still able to run such commands as

```
sudo touch file1
```

And the added rule to sudoers file seems not to work. Why ?

I have logged out/in after modifying the file.

Answer (score 1):

Putting that line in the `sudoers` file allows the user to run `/usr/sbin/useradd` with sudo rights which is required as the command edits /`etc/passwd`. It doesn't prevent the user from doing anything else including using binaries in the user's PATH. In fact, the user can run the command without that line in the `/etc/sudoers` file but it won't have any effect for the reason that I gave above.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I still can't get a grasp on how sudoers file work.

After I put this rule "newuser    ALL=/usr/sbin/useradd" 

newuser is still available to do "sudo passwd username" 

Why ? 

Shouldn't useradd be the only command  is allowed to pass with sudo ?

Comment: @Tomas.R Does the command actually allow `newuser` to run the command after entering the password?

Comment: Solved.
I've removed newuser from sudo group, left that same line in sudoers file and then everything started to work as expected.
Thanks Nasir.